# How to Add Unicode Circled Numbers ① ② ③ to pdf document created with itextpdf 5

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am creating PDF documents in android using itextpdf5, my problem is that I can't use unicode characters, example (\U24ea(⓪) \U2460(①)......... ② ③), I have tried many examples found in the itextpdf 5 documentation but doesn't work, but in the logcat they normally show up. thank you for  any suggestion, here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String DEST = "/file.pdf";
    public static final String cnfreebd = "resources/font/cnfreebd.ttf";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            createPdf();
            PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
            File file = getPublicAlbumStorageDir(DEST);
            pdfView.fromFile(file).load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public File getPublicAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
        return file;
    }

    public void createPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        0);
            }
        } else {
        }
        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {

            File file = getPublicAlbumStorageDir(DEST);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();

            PdfPCell UnicodeCercleNumber1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("\u2460"));
            PdfPCell UnicodeCercleNumber2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("\u2461"));
            PdfPCell UnicodeCercleNumber3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("\u2462"));

            Log.i("tag","(1) => \u2460");
            Log.i("tag","(1) => \u2461");
            Log.i("tag","(1) => \u2462");

            table.addCell(UnicodeCercleNumber1);
            table.addCell(UnicodeCercleNumber2);
            table.addCell(UnicodeCercleNumber3);

            document.add(table);
            document.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the font doesn't support those characters. Please find a font that does and use it in the Paragraph objects.

Answer (score 1):

The font CombiNumerals that you are using, with the file name `cnfreebd.ttf`, does not contain *any* character in the Unicode range for [Enclosed Alphanumerics](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2460.html) `U+2460..U+2473`.

It uses a non-standard Symbol mapping to define "circled numbers" and separate "left hand" and "right hand" halves:

[image: character map, partial detail only]

So to get your output of `⓪ ① ②`, instead of `"\u2460 \u2461 \u2462"`, you need to enter `"\uf070 \uf071 \uf077"`.

Comment: @ZAkZAk: You may need to expand on that. This *is* the font you are using, no denying that. There must be something else wrong, then.

Comment: In the Logcat of Android studio it's working well, but that is not working in the Pdf, I've tried many fonts, it's the same problem doesn't work

Comment: @ZAkZAk: you may need to know that I cannot see your screen. "It does not work" does not help – what do you see? Perhaps the explicit "symbol" encoding `U+F0xx` needs to be plain `U+00xx` instead (without the `U+F000`).